# UITableView Scrolling crashes(segmentation Fault 11) only when tested via instruments tool

Tags: uitableview, scroll, segmentation-fault, xcode-instruments

I use a UITableview to load array of images in a UIImageView embedded in the tableview cell and also load text to UILabel at each row in iPhone.The array size is around 40+. when I scroll UITableView in simulator/device and click each row manually everything is fine.The problem is when i check the same via XCode-Instruments the app crashes(after scoll and selection of  any row).The error thrown is generally

**"Segmentation fault 11".**

What could be the possible reason for this???

PS:comparing to simulator xcode-instruments scrolling is very slow.It scrolls only after some delay.